# Cassandra, aggregate average from table

Tags: cassandra, aggregate, nosql

I have a table with id,name and a map consisting of timestamp and a float as a value pair. What is the syntax to aggregate and get the average float value from all my float values in my map?

Table looks something like this:

```
ID | name | temp map<timestamp, float>

1  |   N  | {'2016-10-27 13:00:00':6.7,'2016-10-27 13:00:00':6.6}
```

Comment: what is your primary key ?

Comment: You can't use avg on collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use aggregate functions on a map. However, since internally a map translates to multiple rows, you could change your data model in order to perform your aggretate functions at partition level. Something like this should suffice:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id int,
    name text,
    ts timestamp,
    value float,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, name), ts);
);

SELECT avg(value) FROM mytable WHERE id = ? AND name = ?;
```